# Sustainsys: error: "IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading '[PII is hidden]' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException'."

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

### Nuget Packages in use:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.App - 2.1.1
2. Microsoft.NETCore.App - 2.1.0
3. Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 - 2.2.0

Dotnet Core version: 2.1.302

### Implementation

Following code is added in the startup.cs file in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```
services.AddSaml2("saml2", options =>
{
    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.EntityId(this.Configuration.Get<AppSetting>().SPEntityId);
    options.SPOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
    options.SPOptions.NameIdPolicy = new Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2NameIdPolicy(true, Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.NameIdFormat.Unspecified);
    options.IdentityProviders.Add(
            new Sustainsys.Saml2.IdentityProvider(
                new Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.EntityId(this.Configuration.Get<AppSetting>().SPMetadata), options.SPOptions)
                {
                    LoadMetadata = true,
                    Binding = Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2BindingType.HttpPost
                });
})
```

The authentication is triggered by following controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/Saml/Callback");
    return Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, "saml2");
}
```

The authentication with the ID server is successfully done and response is received as POST request on `https://SP-Server-xxxx/server/Saml2/Acs` as per XML at the end of this post. However, then following error is returned with HTTP code 500:

```
{
    error: "IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading '[PII is hidden]' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException'."
}
```

Please suggest what is wrong with the setup or the implementation.

Response XML:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:obtained" Destination="https://SP-Server-xxxx/server/Saml2/Acs" ID="XXXXX" InResponseTo="XXXXX" IssueInstant="2018-11-28T06:26:12Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer>https://ID-Server-yyyy/zzzz/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID="XXXXX" IssueInstant="2018-11-28T06:26:12Z" Version="2.0">
        <saml:Issuer>https://ID-Server-yyyy/zzzz/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#yyyyy">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">zzzzz</DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 'removed the signature value' </SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate> 'removed the certificate' </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" NameQualifier="https://ID-Server-yyyy/zzzz/saml2/metadata" SPNameQualifier="https://SP-Server-xxxx">
                abc@xyz.com
            </saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="XXXXX" NotOnOrAfter="2018-11-28T06:31:12Z" Recipient="https://SP-Server-xxxx/server/Saml2/Acs"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-11-28T06:21:12Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-11-28T06:31:12Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://SP-Server-xxxx</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-11-28T06:26:09Z" SessionIndex="XXXXX">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
                <saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>name/password/uri</saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Last Name</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">abc@xyz.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="MiddleName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Middle Name</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">First Name</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="Id" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Id Value</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

**UPDATE:**
After setting `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII` to true the error response is changed as followed:

```
{
    error: "IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'AuthnContext' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'value' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'name/password/uri' at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_DeclarationReference(Uri value) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext..ctor(Uri classReference, Uri declarationReference) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)'."
}
```

Based on the error message I assume the ID server needs to set the AuthnContext with a valid URI. Please confirm.

Following is the Stack-Trace:

```
2018-11-29 08:45:10.700 +01:00 [Debug] Signature validation passed for Saml Response Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Id
2018-11-29 08:45:10.759 +01:00 [Error] Exception is occurred
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenReadException: IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'AuthnContext' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'value' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'name/password/uri'
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_DeclarationReference(Uri value)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext..ctor(Uri classReference, Uri declarationReference)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)'. ---> System.ArgumentException: IDX13300: 'value' must be an absolute Uri, was: 'name/password/uri'
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext.set_DeclarationReference(Uri value)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2AuthenticationContext..ctor(Uri classReference, Uri declarationReference)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationContext(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAuthenticationStatement(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2PSerializer.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSaml2Token(String token)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.CreateClaims(IOptions options, IdentityProvider idp)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.GetClaims(IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.ProcessResponse(IOptions options, Saml2Response samlResponse, StoredRequestState storedRequestState)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, IOptions options)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Service.Provider.Middleware.LanguageHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in X:\Projects\Service-Provider\Middleware\LanguageHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 21
   at Service.Provider.Middleware.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger`1 logger) in X:\Projects\Service-Provider\Middleware\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 22
```

**Update 2**

Thanks for the response @Anders. As we dont have control over the ipd, I have requested the idp developers to consider above change.
But meanwhile we have tried to dig further into the options. I have referred one the documents hosted here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/saml2/latest/saml2.pdf. The section 2.18.1 lists the attributes of  Element. It mentions about `IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse` attribute. Based on the description of the attribute, it seems that making this as `true` will solve the above error.
But I cannot find this attribute while configuring the Compatibility element in SPOtions (`options.SPOptions.Compatibility.IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse` ?)

We are using Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 package version 2.2.0.

Is it so that the `Compatibility.IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse` attribute is not yet available in version 2.2.0 ?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the exception and also set the IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII flag to true to show the actual value in the log message.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the stack trace.

Comment: Yes, the IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse compatibility flag might have been forgotten in the move to 2.0. Please file a bug in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have reported the bug here: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/1045

Comment: It looks like the SPOptions.Compatibility.IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse property was added to the project and it resolved this issue for me. This should be added as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the idp supplies a value `name/password/uri` for `<saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>`. That is a not a valid value, it must be an absolute URI according to the SAML2 specification.

But in this case I think the Idp should omit that element totally.It is already referencing a well known authentication method in the line above: `<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made another update in the question, as there is not enough space in the comments box. I would appreciate if you can take a look.